# Can Kendo Datasource load only $count of data

Tags: kendo-ui

Can someway kendo DataSource load only $count from requested url with filters using odata?

I get this error

```
GET http://localhost:6105/DAL/DataService/LogViewModel/$count/?%24inlinecount=allpages 400 (Bad Request)
```

I want something like

```
GET http://localhost:6105/DAL/DataService/LogViewModel/$count/
```

with filters.

Answer (score 0):

then pass filter parameter to server.and from server return filtered data with count